# Make a string a int if it is a specific string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have a list of strings and want to loop over the list and make the value in the list 0 if it is a specific string. Below is the code I am attempting but it is not working:

```
variable1 = ['None', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'None']   
variable2 = [0 if v is 'None' else v for v in variable1]
```

The result should be: [0, 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 0] but it is not changing the None strings.

Comment: Change `is` to `==`.

Comment: If you've seen `is` and `None` together and are trying to repeat it, note that `None` is very different from string `'None'`...

Comment: Any reason you want the `'None'`s to be the integer `0` and not the word Zero or change the rest of the words to be numerics as well? Seems a little odd...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid `is`, since it requires the strings to be the same object. Use `==` so two distinct string objects can still compare equal.

```
variable2 = [0 if v == 'None' else v for v in variable1]
```